# overlay the grand mean and se into a scatter dot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dot plot created by ggplot, in which I plot every subject's individual responses. The subjects are organized into 3 groups in the plot and I have also estimated and plotted for each subject the mean and se. Now, I want to add at the same plot the grand mean and Se for each group.

This is how I created the first plot:

```
mazeSRDataS1_Errorplot<-ggplot(mazeSRDataS1, aes(Errorfixed, GroupSub, 
       colour=as.factor(Group)))+geom_point() + 
       mytheme3+ ggtitle("mazeSR-S1 Error plot")+ labs(y="Subject ID", x = "Error (degrees)", colour = 
       "Group")+ scale_colour_manual(values = c("brown4", "slategray3", "tan1"))
      mazeSRDataS1_Errorplot + stat_summary(fun = mean, position = 'dodge', shape=1, size=0.5, 
      colour='black') +  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = 'errorbar', colour='black')
```

[image: Individual Responses for maze task, organized per group]

This is how I plotted the grand mean and se for each group. (i first aggregated the data and computed the mean and se for each group).

```
ggplot(meanSEErrorMazeSR1, aes(x=Error, y=Group, colour=Group)) +
   geom_errorbar(aes(xmin=Error-se, xmax=Error+se), width=.1, position='dodge') +
   geom_line(position='dodge') + geom_point(position='dodge')
```

[image: Grand mean and SE for each group]

But, how do I merge these plots and overlay the one over the other?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add y-axis positions to the aggregated data you've made to specify where on the first plot you want them plotted, and then add another `geom_errorbar(data = ...)` where you specify to use the aggregated data e.g.:

```
meanSEErrorMazeSR1 <-
 meanSEErrorMazeSR1 %>%
 mutate(y_position = c(30, 90, 150)  # since you didn't provide a reproducible example you'll need to figure out the best positions yourself here

mazeSRDataS1_Errorplot +
   geom_errorbar(data = meanSEErrorMazeSR1, aes(y = y_position, xmin=Error-se, xmax=Error+se), width=.1)
```

You can toy around with different y-values to use for the positioning of the error bars. In your case, because the y-axis is discrete due to being based on Subject IDs, the y-values will correspond to the order of the subject on the plot - the `y_position = c(30, 90, 150)` above corresponds to the 30th, 90th, and 150th subject, respectively.

Note also that the argument `position='dodge'` is not needed because you're not using a `group` aesthetic!